# Can you use a local script which is not inside a text button to write code for another text button in Luau?

Tags: lua, roblox, luau

The code is fine with no errors, just it doesn't work

Heres the code:

```
local clicks = 0
local plr = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local cm = 1

script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    clicks = clicks + cm
    plr.PlayerGui.ScreenGui.Frame.CookieAmountDisplay.Text = clicks
    script.Parent.BackgroundTransparency = 0
    wait(.1)
    script.Parent.BackgroundTransparency = .5
end)

--This first bit works fine--

game.StarterGui.buybutton.TextButton.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    if clicks == 100 then or if clicks => 100 then
        clicks = clicks - 100
        cm = cm + 1
    else
        print("not enough cookies")
    end

end)
```

I tried to debug but couldnt figure the issue

Comment: Please include a detailed description of WHAT does not work as intended.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
if clicks == 100 then or if clicks => 100 then
        clicks = clicks - 100
        cm = cm + 1
    else
        print("not enough cookies")
    end
```

Is syntactic and logic nonsense. You should get an error messag for this. Not just observe that it doesn't work. The first condition is already included in the second condition and you have too many keywords. This is not how you write a conditional statement. Please read the Lua manual.

You cannot have `or` after `then`, you cannot have an `if` after `or`,  you need an `end` for every `if then` and there is no `=>` operator. It's `>=`

It should look like this

```
if clicks >= 100 then
  clicks = clicks - 100
  cm = cm + 1
else
  print("not enough cookies")
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the fix and explanation of conditionals, but still when I have 100 clicks, and try to purchase no errors happen but it doesnt do anything, so I need to know the answer to my original question which is can you use local scripts inside of other things to control text buttons?

Comment: I cannot make sense of your question. maybe you should clarify how the code differs from your expectations. it does not work is not sufficient. add prints to make sure your code is actually executed